# Defective Nails

Tags: probability

A manufacturer of nails claims that only 3% of its nails are defective. A random sample of 24 nails is selected and it is found that two of them are defective. Is it fair to reject the manufacturer's claim based on the observation?

I know that the number of defective nails is a binomial random variable with n=24 and p=0.03. I don't know how to show whether the claim is true or false.

Comment: You can compute how probable that outcome is *under the assumption that the parameters are right*. This is what statisticians call "test of hypotheses."

Comment: So what would be the probability of two defectives?

Comment: P(X=2)=nCr(24,2)*(0.03)^2*(0.97)^22 right?

Comment: This equals 0.127 but I am still unsure what to do in regards to accepting or rejecting the claim.

Comment: @vonbrand how do I accept or reject the claim?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

$$H_0 : P_0 = 0.03$$

$$H_1 : P_0 > 0.03$$

$$ p = 0.0833$$

z statistic = $$\frac{(0.08333-.03)}{\sqrt{(0.03*.97)/24}} =1.53$$

At a confidence level $\alpha = 0.05$,

$Z_{\alpha} = -1.65$

Reject $H_0$ if Z-statistic < - 1.65 or Z-Statistic

Reject the Claim and conclude that more than 3% of them are defective.

It is a one tailed test with $\alpha$ = .05 and hence you will find the critical value of $Z_{\alpha}$

Comment: I understand your approach (I have taken Business Statistics), however, in my probability class we need to use the binomial random variable approach. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

Binomial (20, 0.03)

Therefore, the probability of find 2 defective nails

1 - The probability that 2 or more nails are defective.

P(X>=2) = 1- P(X=0) - P(X=1) = 1 - (24C0)(1-0.03)^24 - (24) .03*(1-0.03)^23 = 0.161

This is still quite high probability of 16% of finding 2 defective nails; therefore it is not fair to reject the claim.

But if we found 3 defective parts, then P(X>=3) would be 0.03 and suspicious.

Here is Python program to compute the probability

```
#=============
N=24
k=2

p=0.03
q=1-p

s=0
for i in range(3):
    ncr = scipy.misc.comb(N, i)
    pp = p**(i)
    qq = q**(N-i)
    s += ncr * pp * qq

s, 1-s

# output (0.96585321479727937, 0.034146785202720631)
```

Comment: This is basically correct, but I would think it preferable to fix a level of significance *before* actually conducting the test.  That is, state a null and alternative hypothesis and a criterion for rejecting the null hypothesis before actually computing the test statistic.  Otherwise the statement "This is still quite high..." seems like a bit of a handwave.